# How to Dynamically Add External CSS to a Next.js Page Without Warnings?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a situation where I need to add CSS to a page dynamically.

This page's content is dynamic and I receive a raw HTML and a link to a CSS file from a server, and I want to display it on the page.

I tried adding it onto a `<Head>` tag from next.js, and it works, but I get this warning:

```
Do not add stylesheets using next/head (see <link rel="stylesheet"> tag with href="my-url"). Use Document instead.
```

Which points to [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-stylesheets-in-head-component), but since this page is SSR-only I can't dynamically set the CSS there (like using React context, etc.).

Is there any way to have this without warnings? Thanks

Comment: Did you try the answer below? Let me know if it did not work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-helmet` library it maps the head meta tags and styles elements to the `<head></head>` element in the DOM

Example like this:

```js
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    ....
      <Helmet>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Helmet>
    ....
  )
};
```

You won't get warning messages with the [React Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) library.

Comment: Appreciate the enthusiasm but this isn't a good solution. This breaks the Nextjs way of optimising stylesheet and other resource load while adding another package that does the same work as the `Head` tag. It would be better for OP to simply disable the error message than install react helmet to do what Next's `Head` already does.